# django urlconf direct from root to included app logic

Tags: python, django, routes, django-urls, urlconf

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while, but haven't been able to find a solution that works. Maybe someone can help point out a better method!

I'm using my root urlconf to redirect two requests to an included app:

```
url("^about/news/", include("kdi.urls")),
url("^about/recognition/", include("kdi.urls")),
```

And here is the `kdi` app's urlconf:

```
url(r"^$", "kdi.views.news", name="news"),

# this is the pattern that needs to change:
url(r"^$", "kdi.views.recog", name="recog"),
```

It seemed smarter to use the more granular redirection from root `^about/news/` and `^about/recognition` to the `^$` in the app's urlconf. This worked fine with only one pattern, but I'd like to scale it to work for both.

Would something like directing `^about/` from root to the app where I could check for `^/news$` or `^/recognition$` in the `kdi` app be smarter? Would that also be able to use the root's catch-all `^` if no matches were made? Is it possible to check the `request.path` from the urlconf and then use an if statement to direct to the correct view? Or maybe use a `name` field in the root and then access via that name in the app's url patterns?

Just having a little trouble working out the logic with this!

**edit:**

removed `namespace` field from root urlconf to limit confusion

Comment: You have two `include` with same `namespace`, i think they should be different.

Comment: Can I access the pattern via the namespace from the child app? That's an easy fix. I'm looking for a smarter pattern.

Comment: To access pattern you need to use [`django.core.urlresolvers.reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse)

Comment: Thank you, I looked at reverse. That brings up another question: can I name an include pattern `url("^about/news/", include("kdi.urls")),` in the root? The issue with this is that I don't need to access the urls via the template, only to call a specific view in the child app. The view handles much of the logic.

Comment: Would `reverse` work with the namespace?

Comment: you can more urlpattern to wherever you want.

Comment: you can access every bit of django routing system with `reverse`

Comment: I'm sorry, this is still a little difficult for me to understand. From the docs for `reverse`: `viewname can be a URL pattern name or the callable view object`. This still does not clarify whether that will work with `namespace`, or whether I can `name` the root pattern. I understand that I can add more urlpatterns, but that doesn't answer if it will work with `root -> child -> root` catch-all if no matches are made.

Comment: Actually it really hard to follow what you really want here. It's better if you paraphrase your problem. Maybe it would be better if it would be another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing something very bizarre here and I can't work out why.

You should only include your app URLs once. But every URL in that included file needs to be *different*  - otherwise Django can't possibly know how to route the request.

So, the main urls.py should be just:

```
url("^about/", include("kdi.urls")),
```

and the app ones should be:

```
url(r"^news/$", "kdi.views.news", name="news"),
url(r"^recognition/$", "kdi.views.recog", name="recog")
```

Comment: Thank you!! I just figured this out right before your answer, this is the correct answer. I was worried that the request would get stuck in the child app, and not back it back to the catch-all pattern in the root urls. But it does!